# sql query first rows with specific column values

Tags: sql, sqlite

i want to start by saying that i know there are a couple of questions regarding similar problems but they either dont answer my question fully or seem to be incompatible with SQLite.

I want to query all rows with value -1 and the first rows with values other than -1.
And by "first rows" i mean the group of rows that are first with a certain value. the first row is the row that is first stumbled upon depending on the SORT BY clause

An example of the data and outcome:

Data:

```
a   b   -1 
c   d    1
e   f    2
g   h    2
i   j    2 
k   l   -1
```

Result:

```
a   b   -1 
c   d    1
e   f    2
k   l   -1
```

And as said above, i am using a SQLite database

Comment: You need to define what "first rows" means

Comment: oh sorry, i meant the first row to stumble upon depending on the SORT BY clause. Updated the post to reflect this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this as two separate queries, one of them containing an inline view; UNION the two

```
  select blah, blah from T where  ...
UNION
  select * from
  (
    select blah, blah from T where something else order by somecolumn limit 1
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

**With simple example:**

```
> select * from ex1; 
+------+----------+
| id   | name     |
+------+----------+
|    1 | Pirate   |
|    2 | Monkey   |
|    3 | Ninja    |
|    4 | Spagheti |
|    5 | kumar    |
|    6 | siva     |
+------+----------+

> select * from ex1 union select "1", "sing" order by case name when 'sing' then 1 else 2 end, name;
+------+----------+
| id   | name     |
+------+----------+
| 1    | sing     |
| 5    | kumar    |
| 2    | Monkey   |
| 3    | Ninja    |
| 1    | Pirate   |
| 6    | siva     |
| 4    | Spagheti |
+------+----------+
```